ERC4626 Solana alternative
I am familiar with ERC-4626 on Ethereum, which is a tokenized vault standard that facilitates the creation of yield-bearing assets by standardizing the interface for vaults and deposit/withdraw operations. I'm currently working on a project on Solana and looking for a similar solution.
Is there a native Solana program or protocol that mirrors the functionality of ERC-4626? If not, what are the best practices for creating a tokenized vault structure in Solana that allows for similar deposit/withdrawal mechanics, yield strategies, and integrations?
Any examples, frameworks, or guidance on how to approach this in Solana would be much appreciated.
